# change admin view to user view based on the form variable sent to application cfc file in coldfusion and angular js

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion

I have these files:

```
Application.cfc:
     Onrequeststart method:
          session.remoteuser = cgi.REMOTE_USER
```

Based on the this user, the view is:
    Admin view
   or
    user view

I have index.cfm

```
 <div ng-app controller>
    </div>
```

Angular code replaces the view here.

But from admin view i want to create a form which changes the `session.remoteuser` to any user they want to view as. I created a form in `adminview.cfm` page and checking to see if the form is submitted in `application.cfc`. But I see `application.cfc` is fired twice so the view is getting the user id, but goes back to admin id. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue to set the `session.remoteuser` variable in `OnRequestStart()`, structure your logic like this.

```
if the form variable exists
set `session.remoteuser` accordingly

else if `session.remoteuser` does not exist
set `session.remoteuser` to cgi.remoteUser

else
do nothing
```

Then, when the admin person loads the form page, `session.remoteuser` will be set to that person.  It will change when the form is submitted and will not change again for the rest of the session unless there is a way to access the form page again when your application thinks he's the person selected in the form.